# htaccess redirect htm to html (strange behaviour)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have two hosting accounts with different providers.

both sites have the following in the htaccess.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*).htm $1.html
```

On one site (a VPS) it works as expected and

```
//www.example.com/page.htm
```

is correctly forwarded to

```
//www.example.com/page.html
```

But on the other hosting provider (shared hosting. Different provider) it removes the www from the url so goes to:-

```
//example.com/page.html
```

It only strips the www if the htm-to-html redirect occurs. So it's not all pages that have the www removed so it's not a global setting removing www from all urls.

Is that redirect syntax wrong? If so then why does it only affect the domain on one hosting provider. Or is it a setting somewhere else in the website setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*).htm $1.html
> ```

If you don't explicitly include the hostname in the target URL (ie. specify an *absolute* URL) then Apache gets this information from the current server. By default, this will be the hostname used in the request (www, non-www, or whatever). However, if the directive `UseCanonicalName On` is set, the hostname as defined by the `ServerName` directive will be used. This is what I guess is happening.

Unfortunately, on a *shared* server, you are not going to be able to change this behaviour. The `UseCanonicalName` directive can only be set in the server config, not `.htaccess`.

I think the only resolution is to be explicit and specify the canonical hostname in the above directive:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+)\.htm$ http://www.example.com/$1.html
```

Some people recommended to always specify an absolute target URL for redirects to avoid such problems. (Personally, I would only do this out of necessity.)

Comment: Thank you. 
Caused by ServerName directive makes sense. I'll use the absolute target url :)

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question then please mark it as accepted (checkmark on the left) to remove it from the unanswered question queue (this also gives you some rep). Once you have 15+rep then you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated :)